# sqlite timestamp formatting

Tags: sql, database, sqlite, date-formatting

I am trying to work with dates in an sqlite database. I am storing my dates as timestamps, but when I use strftime() to format them to human readable dates I am getting back unxpected results.

Consider the following, I select the current timestamp:

```
SELECT strftime("%s","now");
1281353727
```

Then I try to format a date using the timestamp that I know to represent now expecting to get back a human readable format of todays date:

```
SELECT strftime('%d - %m  - %Y ', 1281353727);
01 - 04  - 3503
```

Instead I get the above result. Is this correct behaviour? am I doing something wrong?

Thanks in advance,

Kevin

Answer (score 75, accepted):

You need to convert the timestamp to datetime first:

```
SELECT strftime('%d - %m  - %Y ', datetime(1281353727, 'unixepoch')) FROM Visits;
```

Comment: Is there a way to have it print the month in text?  ex: August

Comment: Hello reko, If i store this date from Java dateObj.getTime() then will it works with unixepoch option in datetime function?

Comment: In my case I need to devide with 1000.

Answer (score 15):

This worked for me:

```
datetime(visit_date/1000000,'unixepoch')
```

Comment: visit_date/1000000 is very usefull when looking at firefox sqlite records

Comment: Sometimes `/1000` is enough. I.e. in android applications` databases.

Comment: Needed this for firefox `places.sqlite`, worked like a charm! Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

Convert the timestamp to datetime and then format it:

```
SELECT strftime('%d - %m  - %Y ', datetime(1281353727, 'unixepoch', 'localtime')) FROM Visits;
```

#### catch 1

Make sure you add the `localtime` argument. Otherwise you will get a date as perceived by the people living in "Greenwich" (since timestamp started counting at 1/1/1970 00:00 UTC (=GMT) ).

See below how the date output changes depending on whether we use 'localtime', on a workstation with EEST timezone.

```
select strftime('%d - %m  - %Y ', datetime(1623707777, 'unixepoch', 'localtime'))
```

> output: 15 - 06 - 2021

```
select strftime('%d - %m  - %Y ', datetime(1623707777, 'unixepoch'))
```

> output: 14 - 06 - 2021

This is Because at 00:01 EEST, the GMT is still at yesterday.

#### catch 2

Many programs (e.g. ViberPC) add milliseconds (or even microseconds) also to timestamp, in which case you need to first divide by 1000 (or by 1000000 respectively):

```
select strftime('%d - %m  - %Y ', datetime(1623707777421/1000, 'unixepoch', 'localtime'))
```

Comment: Catch 3 - (Using Java notation) 1_000 will convert milliseconds, 1_000_000 will convert MICROseconds, and 1_000_000_000 will convert NANOseconds.

Comment: @user3481644 post updated accordingly.