# SQL Lite - Timestamp

Tags: iphone, sqlite

I've downloaded some iPhone databases and I wonder what the "Timestamp" column does exactly:

411024581.457056 --> how can I get this as readable Date string with time stamp? (dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss)

```
SELECT strftime('%d - %m  - %Y ', datetime(Timestamp, 'unixepoch')), Latitude, Longitude FROM CellLocation
```

This gives me 10-01-1983 which cannot be ok.[image: Example of SQLite database]

I've found that query in another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3439624/sqlite-timestamp-formatting):

Thanks.

Comment: What should be the result of the conversion?

Comment: Could you be more specific about the origin and type of the *iPhone databases*, please?

Comment: @O.R.Mapper My old iPhone and database is cache_encrypedA.db

Comment: So the result should be around 2013?

Comment: @juergend between 2010 and now indeed.

Comment: @juergend: In that case, it might be interesting to note that the *unixepoch* type starts counting in 1970, and 1983 - 1970 = 13 years ... could that DB be using the same format, but starting to count in 2000?

Comment: @Robuust: It would certainly be easier to tell if you could provide a particular timestamp along with the knowledge what date it *should be*. Other than that, please use the opportunity to *link to* the "other question*, so we know what resources you have already found.

Comment: Also, please have a look at [this website](http://www.remkoweijnen.nl/blog/2013/04/14/timestamp-column-in-ios-sqlite-database/). It does indeed suggest interpreting the timestamp like `unixepoch`, but using January 1, 2001 instead of January 1, 1970, as the point of origin.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper Hero! +978307200 it is !

Comment: @O.R.Mapper The date turned out to be yesterday, which is possible since we were using the phone to generate new data.

Comment: @Robuust: For the sake of completeness, I have added this as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As outlined in [this blogpost](http://www.remkoweijnen.nl/blog/2013/04/14/timestamp-column-in-ios-sqlite-database/) (referring to the [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDate_Class/Reference/Reference.html)), the date in such timestamp columns is formatted like with the `unixepoch` type, however, while `unixepoch` asummes January 1, 1970, as its point of origin, Apple uses January 1, 2001.

Therefore, you will need to add the unix timestamp that matches the difference between the two points of origin to the values before converting the result to a readable datetime value - as indicated by the aforementioned [blogpost](http://www.remkoweijnen.nl/blog/2013/04/14/timestamp-column-in-ios-sqlite-database/):

```
datetime(ZONLINEDATE + 978307200, 'unixepoch', 'localtime')
```